# Is it possible to create Ajax-only form (with ajax submit only) in Dojo?

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, dojo

Is it possible to create Ajax-only form in Dojo? I need to make AJAX request on button click/ENTER, but not to refresh the whole page.

This is my simple dialog content:

```html
<div id="myDialog">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td><input name="name" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Owner</td>
      <td><input name="owner" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="buttons">
     <button class='ok'>OK</button>
     <button class='cancel'>Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I convert it to form:

```javascript
form = new Form({action: okAction, method: ''}, dojo.byId('myDialog'))
```

The problem is, that after creating the Dojo form my actions on buttons are no longer called, instead clicking any of them or pressing ENTER causes page refresh.

Is it possible to bind AJAX request with form, instead of whole page submit? In JSF2 it is functioning so.

I'm not a fan of using forms in AJAX applications, but I'd like to use Dojo validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `action` property means you submit the page, causing a complete page refresh (depending on the return value of your `okAction`). If you want to create a  client-side form submit, you need to use the `onSubmit` event handler, for example:

```
form.onSubmit = function(event) {
    // Do this stuff
};
```

Your event handler will probably contain an AJAX request, like the one @James Jithin describes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19314271/1915448).

You can read more about the event handlers at the [API documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/Form).

Answer (score 0):

You can GET or POST the form using dojo. See the form attribute set during the xhr call.

[dojo.xhrPost](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/xhrPost.html)

Here, you can pass the id of the form and get it submitted to the server. Then on the onLoad, you can decide what to do with the response.